# SSH - Seperate grep results with a title

Tags: ssh, grep

I have 3 grep runs and results send to my email:

```
((grep -irl 'abc' /usr/www/users/FTPUSERNAME/*) && (grep -irl 'xyz'  /usr/www/users/FTPUSERNAME/*) && (grep -irl 'xXx' /usr/www/users/FTPUSERNAME/*)) | mail me@mywebsite.com
```

However this creates a combined list of all files.

Is there a way to separate the results by inserting a title to each grep
So the email I get looks something like this:

```
Title for files with abc
/Path-To-File/filename.php
/Path-To-File/filename.php
/Path-To-File/filename.php

Title for files with xyz
/Path-To-File/filename.php
/Path-To-File/filename.php
/Path-To-File/filename.php

Title for files with xXx
/Path-To-File/filename.php
/Path-To-File/filename.php
```

Thanks for the help,
Amit

Comment: Do you REALLY not want to run your 2nd and 3rd greps if the first one doesn't find any matches? What's wrong with `echo "files with abc"; grep 'abc' /wherever/; echo "files with xyz"; grep 'xyz' /wherever; etc.`?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I wouldn't do 3 separate greps just for that and I also wouldn't use grep to find files when there's a tool with a very obvious name for that (`find`), e.g. with GNU awk for IGNORECASE and true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
find /usr/www/users/FTPUSERNAME/ -type f -exec awk '
    BEGIN {
        IGNORECASE = 1
        split("abc xyz xXx",res)
    }
    {
        for (i in res) {
            re = res[i]
            if ($0 ~ re) {
                hits[re][FILENAME]
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        for (i=1; i in res; i++) {
            re = res[i]
            printf "Title for files with %s\n", re
            for (file in hits[re]) {
                print file
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' {} + |
mail ...
```

Note that given the above if you need to add a 4th regexp you just add it to the `split()` call, it only searches for files once instead of 3 times, you're only opening each found file once instead of 3 times,  and you can format the output of the search however you like. There's various ways it could be optimized for speed if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by pre-pending each of your grep commands with an echo. Here is your command slightly modified :

```
$ ((echo "Title for files with abc" && grep -irl 'abc' /usr/www/users/FTPUSERNAME/*) && ( echo "Title for files with xyz" && grep -irl 'xyz'  /usr/www/users/FTPUSERNAME/*) && ( echo "Title for files with xXx" && grep -irl 'xXx' /usr/www/users/FTPUSERNAME/*)) | mail me@mywebsite.com
```